# Archiving multiple targets at same time

Tags: ios, xcode

I have multiple targets for my iOS app. I want to archive all the targets simultaneously. I found this link but could not find anything in this link . Is there any way to archive and create different .ipa files simultaneously.

i have 100 of targets in one project. how to build and archive all targets at simultaneously like android flavour.

Comment: Er, what link did you find?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to archive all targets, but also for submitting all .ipa files, you can use Application loader to upload all archived file to App Store.